# How can we give height based on content of a cell in xlsx?

Tags: excel, xml, xlsx

I am trying to create an Excel file through XML, How can we give a height based on the content of the cell. Here I manually added ht=27 in a row, is there any other option to change the height based on the content? So it will look nice even if it is 3 lines or 10 lines

```
<row r="26" spans="1:26" ht="27" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3">
       <c r="B26" s="3"/>
       ......
       ......
       <c r="I26" s="41" t="inlineStr">
           <is><t>long text/short text (dynamic text)</t></is>
       </c>
       ......
       ......
       <c r="Z26" s="3"/>
   </row>
```

Any idea/suggestions, how to do that or alternate option

Comment: What are you using to generate the XML file?

Comment: pebble template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would completely remove the `ht` and the `x14ac:dyDescent` attribute from the `row`'s XML, then the height will be auto calculated by content as long as there are not any merged cells in that row.

So

```
   <row r="26" spans="1:26">
       <c r="B26" s="3"/>
       ......
       ......
       <c r="I26" s="41" t="inlineStr">
           <is><t>long text/short text (dynamic text)</t></is>
       </c>
       ......
       ......
       <c r="Z26" s="3"/>
   </row>
```

should look as you want as long as there are not any merged cells in that row and `s="41"` points to a cell style where `wrapText` is set true.

Why to remove the explicit set of `ht` should be self explanatory. If not present, implicit height calculation will be done.

Why additional the remove of `x14ac:dyDescent` is necessary? [Documentation of 2.5.3 dyDescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/f11dfda4-46de-4035-8418-d76b0d3898f1) tells it:

> The **dyDescent** attribute has a side effect; it sets the
> **customHeight** attribute to true even if the **customHeight** attribute is explicitly set to false.

So if set `x14ac:dyDescent`, then no implicit height calculation will be done.

Comment: is there any way to achieve the same, if there is a merged cell?

Comment: @Indian: No. There is not any auto height for merged cells in Excel. Try it yourself. Put multiline text in merged cells in Excel GUI. Then try to use Format - AutoFit Row Height from start ribbon. It will not work.